# Dictionary with lists as values: how to transform the lists in nested dictionaries? (python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'key1' : ['1640', 315], 'key2' : ['1638', 750, 340, '1639', 450, 300]}
```

I want to transform the lists in nested dictionary where the string ('1640', '1638', '1639') is the key and the following integers are the correspondent values.

I have tried itertools izip, it works, but only with the first element, so I got back

```
{key1 : {'1640' : 315}, key2 : {'1638' : 750}}
```

while the desired output is:

```
{key1: {'1640' : 315}, key2 : {'1638' : [750, 350], '1639' : [450, 300}}
```

EDIT:

The problem I need to solve is the last step of a parsing project. This is the code so far for the first part of the project.

```
Book_chap = open('file.htm').read()

#get a list of all the strings between paragraphs tags
pattern1 = re.compile(r'\<p>(.*?)\</p>')
list_of_strings = re.findall(pattern1, Book_chap)

my_dict = {}
#dict2 = {}

for element in list_of_strings[1:]: #do not consider the first paragaph 

    substitute = element.replace('�', '@') #replace unrecognized character with snail

    names = re.compile(r'(\@.\s?[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+(?=\s[A-Z])(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+)+)') #regex to get names + surnames or @ + surnames
    names_ = re.findall(names, substitute)

    years_and_cases = re.compile(r'\s\d{1,4}\:.*?\.')
    yc_find = re.findall(years_and_cases, substitute)

    for k in names_:
        for v in yc_find:
            out = "".join(c for c in v if c not in ('!','.',':', ',')) #remove punctuation from the string, keep only the numbers
            out = out.split() #get tokens
            out = [int(i) if len(i)<4 else i for i in out] #{k: v } k type = string, v type = int
            my_dict[k] = out
            #out = iter(out)
            #outt = dict(izip(out, out))
            #dict2[k] = outt   this spits back only the first key element in the list plus the first value bound to that key


print my_dict
```

I have considered to use the type of the elements in the lists of values:

```
d2 = {}
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    for item in v:
        if type(item) == 'str':
            d2[k][item] = {} #string items are keys in the nested dict

        else:
           #integer items are values (?)
```

this doesn't work even for the first part: I get a second dictionary with the same keys as the first one, the value is an empty nested dictionary I don't get the inner keys (which should be the strings).
I have checked some previous questions about dict comprehensions, but it seems to me they work with steps/regular intervals and my lists of values are irregular (I may have one or more keys, each key may have one or more values)

Comment: Well, you'll have to think of an algorithm to do what you want. What do you expect, some kind of built-in magic for your very specific problem? Have you tried anything else besides `izip`?

Comment: Edit your post with the code you've tried so far

Comment: @user5608277, First solve the problem of converting a list to a dictionary, the generalizing that to lists in dictionary's values should be *trivial*.

Comment: @JoshJ, I have added the original code and what I have tried (or thought about).

Comment: `out = [int(i) if len(i)<4 else i for i in out]` - that's a strange processing step to apply. In any case, this is probably where you should be building the inner dict.

Comment: @user2357112 I thought it may be useful to differentiate the values in order to use all of those that are strings as keys of the nested dict and those that are integers as values.

Comment: What's that punctuation you're removing? It seems like it probably provides the key-value separation you need. The length-dependent step seems pretty fragile.

Comment: the original value looked like ['1638: 750, 350.'], it was a unique string. The length is consistent throughout all the file, and this script is intended to be used only for this specific file, but I know that it's not good coding.

Comment: Yeah, you should probably use the periods, colons, and commas to separate your data. Right now, you're throwing away most of the structure of the input and then trying really kludgy ways to recover it.